How can I align my player to a ledge (Unity 3D)?
I am working on a game with a grapple system similar to the Batman Arkham games. Right now, you can target a point on a ledge and teleport to it (Teleporting is just for testing) and then hang on it. My issue is that I need the player to properly align with the ledge, by moving back from it slightly (Can't use transform.forward because the player would move back from the direction they were facing before grappling, which could be any direction) and then rotating to face it. How would I go about this?
This is my current grappling code (I figured posting the whole script wasn't necessary because this is the only code I need to edit):
void Update()
    {
        grapplePointPosition = findGrapplePoint.WinnerGrapple.WorldPosition;

        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Grapple") && GetComponent<BatmanMovement>().isGrounded()) {
            Grapple(grapplePointPosition);
        }
    }

    void Grapple(Vector3 newPosition)
    {
        GetComponent<BatmanMovement>().enabled = false;
        anim.SetBool("Hanging", true);
        transform.position = newPosition;

        AlignWithLedge(newPosition);
    }

    void AlignWithLedge(Vector3 ledgePosition)
    {
        // This is where I would put the aligning code
        // The current stuff just moves the player down slighlt so they aren't floating

        Vector3 offsetPos = transform.position;
        offsetPos.y -= 2f;
        transform.position = offsetPos;
        hanging = true;
    }

I've tried calculating the ledge's surface normal to figure out how to move the player back from the ledge, but I don't have much experience with that and ended up giving up.

I assume your grapplePointPosition is calculated using a raycast of some kind, those return a RaycastHit which have a normal property

I do not use Raycasts, I find all the possible points in my Screen Space and then choose the one closest to the center of the screen.

Oh the points are gameobjects? Why not store rotation to place the player inside those gameobjects then?

They're also not GamObjects. I essentially set nodes at corner of structures and then a lines are created between them. Any point on that line is a Grapple Point, and the one at closest to the center of the screen is targeted.

Then you can use the two connecting nodes' positions to get the normals: Vector3(-(point1.z - point0.z), 0, (point1.x - point0.x)) (assuming clockwise ordering), or Vector3((point1.z - point0.z), 0, -(point1.x - point0.x)) (assuming counterclockwise ordering)
